# Re-size a current browser window on minimize to specific width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

How can I set height, width and set the position of the current browser window on minimize using jQuery like when user minimize the current browser it should display with a specific height and width in the left bottom (small window) corner of my screen (same as teams)
does it possible?

Comment: JS can't access the size of the minimized browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize window if it's not opened with `window.open()`

And you can't distinguish between minimizing the window and switching to a different tab.

---

There are 2 ways:

- open current window with `window.open()` at first.

or

- open new window when current window is minimized.

---

code for the second one:

```
var url = "http://google.com";
var options =   "resizable"+
                ",height=500,width=500"+
                ",top=9999,left=0"; // left bottom

// on browser visibility changed
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
    if(document.hidden){
        // on window minimized (or tab switched)
        window.open(url, "window name", options);
    }
    else{
        // on window restored
    }
}, false);
```